# Filter Json and Add Custom Markers

Tags: javascript, json, leaflet

I'm trying to import a json file from my database and add custom layers with different marker styles. When I import the json and do json.map, it works as one layer with all the lat/lng data. When I do json.filter, if category == "what i want", add marker... It pulls the data, puts it in a variable, but won't use it as a layer.

NOTE:
I'm using Javascript and Sequelize. My leaflet map is importing from mapbox. The program is fully functional as is, but I'm trying to add extra features for sorting data and viewing pleasure.

```
  fetch('https://agile-mesa-12521.herokuapp.com/api')
    .then(function(response) {
      return response.json();
    }).then(function(complaintJson){
      let lMarkerArray = complaintJson.filter((complaint) => {
        if(complaint.category == "pothole"){
        return L.marker([complaint.lat, complaint.long])
      }
    })
    console.log(lMarkerArray)
      let overlayMaps = { "Complaints": L.layerGroup(lMarkerArray)}
      let streetView = {"Street View": L.tileLayer('https://api.tiles.mapbox.com/v4/{id}/{z}/{x}/{y}.png?access_token={accessToken}', {
          attribution: 'Map data &copy; <a href="https://www.openstreetmap.org/">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors, <a href="https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/2.0/">CC-BY-SA</a>, Imagery © <a href="https://www.mapbox.com/">Mapbox</a>',
          minZoom: 10,
          id: 'mapbox.streets',
          accessToken: 'pk.eyJ1IjoicmxvcmVuemluaSIsImEiOiJjanR5Z3R2bjQxNjlxM3lvNTV4ZnMxOXAyIn0.xxNzHRkLduHYsYIMoCvGCA'
      }).addTo(mymap)}
      L.control.layers(streetView, overlayMaps).addTo(mymap)
    })
})
```

Take out the if(complaint...) and change complaintJson.filter to .map and it works with all the incoming data.

Any suggestions on how to create multiple variables, assign them to different categories from my complaintJson file, and then give them custom markers?

```
  fetch('https://agile-mesa-12521.herokuapp.com/api')
    .then(function(response) {
      return response.json();
    }).then(function(complaintJson){
      let lMarkerArray = complaintJson
  .filter(complaint => complaint.category == "pothole")
  .map(complaint => L.marker([complaint.lat, complaint.long]));
        // return L.marker([complaint.lat, complaint.long])
    // })
    console.log(lMarkerArray)
      let overlayMaps = { "Complaints": L.layerGroup(lMarkerArray)}
      let streetView = {"Street View": L.tileLayer('https://api.tiles.mapbox.com/v4/{id}/{z}/{x}/{y}.png?access_token={accessToken}', {
          attribution: 'Map data &copy; <a href="https://www.openstreetmap.org/">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors, <a href="https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/2.0/">CC-BY-SA</a>, Imagery © <a href="https://www.mapbox.com/">Mapbox</a>',
          minZoom: 10,
          id: 'mapbox.streets',
          accessToken: 'pk.eyJ1IjoicmxvcmVuemluaSIsImEiOiJjanR5Z3R2bjQxNjlxM3lvNTV4ZnMxOXAyIn0.xxNzHRkLduHYsYIMoCvGCA'
      }).addTo(mymap)}
      L.control.layers(streetView, overlayMaps).addTo(mymap)
    })
})
```

Updated code with suggestions to filter then map.

Oxnoob resolved my issue. Thanks!

Comment: you have to remove theother  `})` as well, or the `console.log(); ...` statements aren't in the callback function of the promise.

Comment: Oof. Nice catch. Works like a charm. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because filter returns a subset of the original array, (with only the elements to which the function returns a truthy value), you can't change the element itself like you did with map.

I think what you want to do is:

```
let lMarkerArray = complaintJson
  .filter(complaint => complaint.category == "pothole")
  .map(complaint => L.marker([complaint.lat, complaint.long]));
```

Comment: When I try it like that, I get an error message saying lMarkerArray is not defined. I get what you're suggesting though.

Comment: Can you give an updated version of your code? @r-lorenzini